# htaccess not finding .htpasswd file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to password protect a directory on my site. I can get the .htaccess working so that when I visit the directory a password prompt is shown, however when I put the correct credentials that I've stored within my .htpasswd file I am not granted access. The password prompt just pops up again.

I believe it's a problem with the path to the .htpasswd file in the .htaccess file. I've checked my document root (_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) and it shows that the root is this:

```
/var/www/vhosts/myurl.info/httpdocs
```

so my .htaccess looks like so:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/myurl.info/httpdocs/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

I've put the .htpasswd in the root document folder (httpdocs).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Are you sure your htpasswd is in correct format? `username:passwordhash`

Comment: I used to hat a problem that apache couldn't read/write. Might be this?

Comment: file permissions on directories and files are correct....apache can access those files

Comment: htpasswd is in format myuser:mypass

Comment: are you sure its in the correct place ? mostly if you have a httpdocs it appears under home/username/www/ It may be pointing at an empty file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the path were invalid, you'd get a 500 error or something. Since the browser prompts for password, most likely the path is correct. However You need to make sure you generated the htpasswd correctly. Check this- http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: YES! I was doing everything correctly but I didn't realise that my password needed to be encrypted! I was just doing myusername:plainpassword

Comment: I didn't realize I was *that* slow in typing a comprehensive answer! @elduderino

Comment: Upvote for you @AlvinWong anyway. elduderino I think httpdocs could be your web root directory. I highly suggest you move your .htpasswd file from httpdocs folder to somewhere which is not accessible to public.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the `.htpasswd` is in the format of `user:passwordhash`, where `passwordhash` can be of the following types:

- CRYPT (a kind of cryptographic hashing, only the first 8 characters are supported so beware not to choose a password longer than 8 characters)
- MD5 (an Apache-specific algorithm that make uses of the `MD5` function, a bit similar to cryptographic hashing)
- SHA1 (only one possible outcome per password, so the resulting hash can probably be reversed if a hacker managed to get the `.htpasswd` file)
- <s>*Plain text*</s> (you can always create this format, but note that "the httpd daemon will **only** accept plain text passwords on *Windows, Netware and TPF*". Also **using plain text is unsafe** because if a hacker gets the file he will know all your passwords)

Normally you will choose `CRYPT`, but if you have a longer password consider `MD5` or `SHA1`. Never try to use plain text as it is not supported on Linux and is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove line "AuthGroupFile /dev/null" - I don't specify it if not using group file...

If it doesn't help - have a look in error.log of apache... it'll give you hints. Of post relevant part of the error.log here...